# Does Spark support workflow management?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to create a long running Spark job with the possibility of having to resume it from where it left off in the case of a crash. Does Spark support this and any other workflow management features? I saw some references to DataFrame checkpoints and Spark Structured Streaming checkpoints, but not sure if that offers what I'm looking for.

Is there any workflow management tool that Spark people would recommend? I know of Airflow, Oozie, temporal.io.